# How to prove there are $n$ independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A given $n\times n$ matrix $B$ of real entries obeys $B^{2}=-I$.

I know that $B$ has only 2 eigenvalues $i,-i$ and that $n$ has to be even. Therefore each eigenvalue must have $n/2$ multiplicity. How do I prove that there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: Observe that $x^2+1$ is the characteristics polynomial as well as minimal polynomial of $B$ which has distinct linear factors and hence $B$ is diagonalizable and therefore it has $n$ linearly independent eigen vectors.

Comment: Just to clarify: $x^2 +1$ is not the characteristic polynomial of $B$ unless $n=2$. But it *is* the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Any way of showing that there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors without invoking that $B$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @csprun you are correct.

Comment: Those two conditions are equivalent, and @Dbchatto67 hasn't invoked it, he has proved it (albeit concisely). One can prove that if a matrix $B$ satisfies a polynomial with no repeated roots, e.g. $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$, then it's diagnalizable (in an algebraic closure of the ground field). Again, you can prove this easily with JNF.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same as what @Dbchatto67 says in the comments, but if you know about Jordan normal form (very much worth learning if not), then you can solve this easily by thinking in JNF. A $k\times k$ Jordan block (over $\mathbb{C}$)
$$J = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$
does not satisfy $J^2 = -I$ unless $\lambda = \pm i$ (as you already saw) *and* $k=1$. So the JNF of $B$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is diagonal and there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That is precisely what I was trying to say. Very nice explanation @csprun.